# OnPhotonSerializeView callback is not working in photon pun2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, photon

I'm creating multi-play game using photon pun2.

I'm setted the components inherited from the IPunObservable to object contain a photon view.
but, **OnPhotonSerializeView** is never called.

This code is a function that synchronizes the position and others. but, it didn't work. and it doesn't catch a break point.

This object is created through **PhotonNetwork.Instantiate**, and here is the contents of the source and prefab.

```
using Photon.Pun;
using UnityEngine;

public class Character : MonoBehaviourPun, IPunObservable
{
    [Header("Properties")]
    public float hp;
    public float maxHp;
    public bool isMoving;
    public float moveSpeed;
    public Vector2 moveDirection;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.AddCallbackTarget(this);
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.RemoveCallbackTarget(this);
    }

/** skip **/

    public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
    {
        Debug.Log(nameof(OnPhotonSerializeView));

        if (stream.IsWriting)
        {
            stream.SendNext(transform.position);
            stream.SendNext(hp);
            stream.SendNext(maxHp);
            stream.SendNext(moveSpeed);
            stream.SendNext(isMoving);
            stream.SendNext(moveDirection);
        }
        else if (stream.IsReading)
        {
            transform.position = (Vector3)stream.ReceiveNext();
            hp = (float)stream.ReceiveNext();
            maxHp = (float)stream.ReceiveNext();
            moveSpeed = (float)stream.ReceiveNext();
            isMoving = (bool)stream.ReceiveNext();
            moveDirection = (Vector2)stream.ReceiveNext();
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Or is there anything I missed about **OnPhotonSerializeView**?

I understand that it repeats every second as many frames as specified by **PhotonNetwork.SerializationRate** or **PhotonNetwork.SendRate**.

sorry about my poor english...

I want to know about is why not **OnPhotonSerializeView** called or my wrong knowledge about that.

**+added**

I'm checked that **OnPhotonSerializeView** called when player entered two or more. but, not.

I'm used **PhotonTransformView**. but, it's not synchronized transform too.

PunRPC is working normally.

this is skipped source

```
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            MoveEvent();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void MoveEvent()
    {
        isMoving = moveDirection != Vector2.zero;

        if (isMoving)
        {
            transform.position = transform.position + moveDirection * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
```

**++added**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha4GP.png)

i founded cloned object on other client view. and it's properties are empty. why is this happening?

Comment: Your screenshot shows a `Guard Character` but your script is `Character` .. is this inherited?

Comment: yes, i forget to tell about that. i'm modified something in source for question.

Comment: Do you have multiple players in the room?  I see a comment mentioning it does not run if there is only one player in the room.  I cannot test to confirm as that seems incorrect and odd, but worth a shot.

Comment: i already did it. I will add contents that i did to body that people don't get confused.

Comment: Can you verify that, when instantiated at runtime, the PhotonView shows a ViewID, and it's consistent across the two clients?

Comment: check my ++added contents. it occur problem that similar like you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is problem on creating room! i will check my room options or typed lobby. Thank you to everyone try to help me.